# Displaing information Angular 6

Tags: angular5, angular6

I am trying make quiz app. I need to display list of questions sequentially not as a list. I cant make {{question}} displays, because it is undefined till service will have worked. How to do it right?

questionform.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Question} from "../question";
import {questionService} from "../question.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questionform',
  templateUrl: './questionform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questionform.component.css']
})
export class QuestionformComponent implements OnInit {

  questions: Question[];
  question: string = this.question[0].question;

  constructor(private questionService: QuestionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getQuestions();
  }

  getQuestions(): void{
    this.questionService.getQuestions().subscribe(questions => this.questions = questions);
  }

}
```

questionform.component.html

```
<p>{{question}}</p>
<button onClick()="next()">next</button>
```

Comment: could you clarify what "sequentially" means for you? I can't differentiate it from just "a list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the information that you try to show is that there is no questions when the component is initialized and `question: string = this.question[0].question` is executed.

If you want to store the first question inside `question` you need to add that line also in the `subscribe` method like this:

```
getQuestions(): void{
    this.questionService
        .getQuestions()
        .subscribe(questions => {
            this.questions = questions;
            this.question = this.questions[0].question;
         });
}
```

So in this way you can be sure that the data is there when you are initializing your data.

Hope it helps!